# Casting an array of standard-layout objects to array of elements

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, standard-layout

In C++, it is legal to `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to a [standard-layout type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) `S` to a pointer to any of the members of `S`, possibly using [the `offsetof` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). If `S` only has one member, then `offsetof` is not necessary and this is legal:

```
struct S {
    int x;
};

static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<S>);

void f(S s) {
    // this is legal for standard-layout classes, offsetof the first member is zero
    S *s0 = &s;
    int *x0 = reinterpret_cast<int *>(s0);
}
```

But now suppose I have an array of `S`:

```cpp
S arr_s[10];
```

I can legally let the array decay to a pointer

```cpp
S *s0 = arr_s;
```

and I can legally cast the pointer to an `int *`:

```cpp
int *x0 = reinterpret_cast<int *>(s0);
```

Does that mean that I can access the whole array via `x0`? Is it legal to index `x0` beyond 0? I am pretty sure the answer is no, because `S` may have more than one member. But if we restrict ourselves to the case where `S` has exactly one member, can I somehow legally treat an array of `S` as an array of `int`?

Comment: If the struct has the same size and alignment as its member, probably yes. You could have a `short` aligned as a `long` inside the struct and that would not fly, even if there is only one member.

Comment: The question asks about casting to an array of elements. But an `int*` is not an array of ints. There is a problem right there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and I can legally cast the pointer to an int *:

Yes.

> Does that mean that I can access the whole array via x0? Is it legal to index x0 beyond 0?

No. You can form, dereference and access through `x0+0`. You can also form `x0+1`, but it will be the one-past-the-object pointer and may not be dereferenced. You can't form pointers to any other index. The `int*` that you receive from the cast points to a single `int` object that is not part of an array of `int`. Such cases are treated as if they belonged to an array of size `1` and pointer arithmetic is only defined inside that array.

> I am pretty sure the answer is no, because S may have more than one member. But if we restrict ourselves to the case where S has exactly one member, can I somehow legally treat an array of S as an array of int?

No, the layout of the class has no impact at all, except that for a non-standard layout class the `reinterpret_cast` itself will not work as intended and even accessing at index `0` or any pointer arithmetic (including `+0`) will be UB, because in that case `reinterpret_cast` will not even result in a pointer to the `int` object. You would then be trying to access or do pointer arithmetic on an object of a type that is not similar to the (pointer-removed) expression type.

There is currently no way to achieve what you want.

> In C++, it is legal to reinterpret_cast a pointer to a standard-layout type S to a pointer to any of the members of S, possibly using the offsetof macro.

This is technically not possible beyond the first element either at the moment. But that is a defect in the standard. It currently doesn't correctly specify that `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>` should yield a pointer to the object representation (which is the only way that `offset` could be used). The details of this specification will matter in terms of which `offsetof` constructs have UB and which have not. This is not straight-forward.

---

All of this is in terms of standard guarantees (C++17 or later). Whether this will cause problems on compilers in practice is a different question. In practice (I think) you are probably fine on current compilers as long as you make sure that all alignment requirements are fulfilled and sizes match. Note that the latter is not guaranteed by only having one member in the class. There could still be padding at the end.

Answer (score -3):

Yes because the legality of accessing the array elements via x0 depends on the properties of the type S. If S has only one member, as in the provided code, then accessing the array elements via x0 is legal. This is because the reinterpret_cast effectively treats the array of S as an array of int.

However as you mentioned, this approach is only valid when S has exactly one member.